# Undraw a list of graphical objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

From the following list of plotted graphical objects, I am told to `undraw` all of them, one by one, but I don't know how.

```
win = GraphWin("plot", 500, 500)          #defines the graphical window to work with
win.setBackground("white")                #white background
win.setCoords(0, -10, 10, 10)             #the specified coordinates are as such
Line(Point(0,0), Point(10,0)).draw(win)   #draws the x-axis for clarity

def plot(fun, color):       #user defines a function (of x) and the colour it appears with

listP = []

for i in range(0,1001):     #I am told to sample points in the interval x(0,10) at the 
                            #specified rate (one thousand times)
    x = i/100                                       
    try:
        y = eval(fun)                                
    except(ZeroDivisionError, ValueError):   #to avoid program crash on division by 0
        pass                                 #or definition errors like log(x) for x=0
    else:
        p = Point(x,y)                       #for every x,y combination, defines a point
        p.draw(win)                          #which is then plotted
        p.setFill(color)                     #and coloured according to specification
        listP.append((x,y))                  #and then added to a list of points

return(listP)                                #in the end I am told to return the list
```

Now, given this list, I am told that I should *then* `undraw` every point, but how do I call on existing points/graphical objects? Trying to now define a point `p = Point(x,y)` for every set of `x,y` in the list `listP` only creates new points, so I can't use `p.undraw()` then.

I am tempted to use the "poor man's" undraw of simply drawing a white box over the existing points, but the exercise specifically says that I am supposed to undraw point for point, and it has me absolutely stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up my code and fixed the problem, using some Global definitions

```
def plot(window, fun, color):

    global win
    win = GraphWin(window, 500, 500)                        
    win.setBackground("white")
    win.setCoords(0, -10, 10, 10)
    Line(Point(0,0), Point(10,0)).draw(win)

    global listU
    listU = []
    listP = []

    for i in range(0,1001):                             
        x = i/100                                       
        try:
            y = eval(fun)                                
        except(ZeroDivisionError, ValueError):          
            pass
        else:
            p = Point(x,y)                              
            p.draw(win)
            p.setFill(color)
            listP.append((round (x,2),round(y,2)))     
            listU.append(p)                             

    return(listP)
```

First, I moved the `win` definition back into the plot method, but made it global, so it can work with other methods - specifically, the `undraw` method below. Second, I added a new list (also global) called `listU` to which I append the points themselves, not just their coordinates (as in `listP`).

Now, I make a new method:

```
def undraw_all():

    for i in listU:
        i.undraw()
```

Which now goes through the list of the actual points (rather than the coordinate list `listP` which I was originally looking at), and undraws each one in succession. Simple and clean.